# The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a listview dialog to bind a data to that listview.

```
private void BindListView(string DCLookupMstr_Value, int reportCatId, string DCLookup_Value = null)

    {          

         using (Model.OperationalAnalyticsEntities oadb = new Model.OperationalAnalyticsEntities())
            {
                var res = oadb.prGetDailyCensusLookup(DCLookupMstr_Value, reportCatId, DCLookup_Value);
                Session["LookupValues"] = res;
                lvLookup.DataSource = res.ToList();
                lvLookup.DataBind();
            }            
    }
```

And I put a search box(textbox) on that listview dialog. If user type any text/chars, using linq query..populate the listview again with the values which contains given chars. My code is below

```
protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = txtSearch.Text;
        //var list = new List<Model.prGetDailyCensusLookup_Result>();
        var lookUpValue = Session["LookupValues"] as ObjectResult<Model.prGetDailyCensusLookup_Result>;
        var list = lookUpValue.Where(x => x.DCLookup_Value.Contains(text));

        lvLookup.DataSource = list.ToList();
        lvLookup.DataBind();  
     }
```

I am getting the "result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once" where ever i added .ToList(). I am not sure what did I miss.

Please Help!

Comment: The error message is rather self-explanatory.  You're trying to get the results of a query more than once.  You can't do that.  What about that don't you understand?  You're also trying to execute a query that's based on a disposed data source, so that is likely going to cause problems for you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `BindListView`, when you do `.ToList()`, it enumerates the query for the first time. And what you store in the session is the query itself. When you do `.ToList()` again in `txtSearch_TextChanged`, it enumerates the query a second time, which is not supported.

You should store the result of `.ToList()` in the session, rather than the query:

```
Session["LookupValues"] = lvLookup.DataSource = res.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You value you are storing in `Session` is the LINQ query, not the result of the query.  The second time it is used (the `list.ToList()`) it throws this error.

This is easily fixed by storing the result as a list in `Session` instead.

```
var res = oadb.prGetDailyCensusLookup(DCLookupMstr_Value, reportCatId, DCLookup_Value)
              .ToList();
Session["LookupValues"] = res;
lvLookup.DataSource = res;
lvLookup.DataBind();
```